# CoreData - Deleting row from tableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, delete-row

I need some help with this code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        println("section and row \(indexPath.section) \(indexPath.row) ")
        if self.fetchedResultsController == nil {
            println("error when trying to delete object from managed object")

        } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
            moc?.deleteObject(detailsArray[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject)
            detailsArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

            var error: NSError?
            moc?.save(&error)
        }
    }
// MARK: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate
    func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        self.exerciseTableView.beginUpdates()
    }
    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController,
        didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject,
        atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?,
        forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType,
        newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?)
    {
        switch type {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:
            // Note that for Insert, we insert a row at the __newIndexPath__
            if let insertIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                self.exerciseTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([insertIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete:
            // Note that for Delete, we delete the row at __indexPath__
            if let deleteIndexPath = indexPath {
                self.exerciseTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([deleteIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update:
            // Note that for Update, we update the row at __indexPath__
            if let updateIndexPath = indexPath {
                let cell = self.exerciseTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(updateIndexPath)
                let details = self.fetchedResultsController!.objectAtIndexPath(updateIndexPath) as? TrainingDetails

                cell!.textLabel!.text = "\(details!.exerciseName)"
                cell!.detailTextLabel!.text = "Sets: #\(details!.setsNumber) Reps: #\(details!.repsNumber)"
            }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Move:
            // Note that for Move, we delete the row at __indexPath__
            if let deleteIndexPath = indexPath {
                self.exerciseTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([deleteIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            }

            // Note that for Move, we insert a row at the __newIndexPath__
            if let insertIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                self.exerciseTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([insertIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            }
        }    }

    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController,
        didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo,
        atIndex sectionIndex: Int,
        forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType)
    {
        switch type {
        case .Insert:
            let sectionIndexSet = NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex)
            self.exerciseTableView.insertSections(sectionIndexSet, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        case .Delete:
            let sectionIndexSet = NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex)
            self.exerciseTableView.deleteSections(sectionIndexSet, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        default:
            ""
        }
    }
    func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        exerciseTableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

So, the problem is whenever I try to delete something from the table view, it only runs properly if it's the first item in the table view. If I try to delete any other item that's not the first one, the app crashed and it says **Array index out of range**.

I don't get where's my mistake. Can someone help me?

I hope we can crack this! Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

cellForRowAtIndexPath function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("exerciseCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        let details = fetchedResultsController!.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! TrainingDetails
        cell.textLabel!.text = "\(details.exerciseName)"
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "Sets: #\(details.setsNumber) Reps: #\(details.repsNumber)"

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) { 

        println("section and row \(indexPath.section) \(indexPath.row) ") 
        if self.fetchedResultsController == nil { 
             println("error when trying to delete object from managed object") 

        } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) { 

         switch editingStyle { 

               case .Delete: 
                     moc?.deleteObject(fetchedResultsController?.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! TrainingDetails) 
                     moc?.save(nil) 

              case .Insert: 
                        break 
              case .None: 
                        break 
             } 
        } 
     }
```

This might be helpful.

Comment: I don't know what happened but now it's crashing in this line ** moc?.deleteObject(detailsArray[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject)** saying Array index out of range!

Comment: Can add the code for deleteObject function? Are you using NSPredicate for deleting the particular data?

Comment: I don't have a "deleteObject" function. The code regarding the deletion of the item in the table view is what I showed you! What else do I have to do?

Comment: Comment the "deleteObject" line and try it again and also comment the line "moc?.save()". I have also updated the answer.

Comment: If I comment the deleteObject line, the crash happens in the next line: detailsArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row). We are trying to delete the object from the detailsArray. Maybe the error is in there? Shouldn't we try to delete the object from the fetchedResultsController?

Comment: Add your "cellForRowAtIndexPath" tableview function in the question. Are you using "details" array to add the values in the cell? If your are using "details" array then your are deleting the value from wrong array.

Comment: I edited the question. I'm using fetchedResultsController to add the values to the cell. How can we use it the same way to delete the values from the cell?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87794/discussion-between-karlos-and-nicholas-piccoli).